# How to loop through all and replace some sheets in an Excel workbook

Tags: vba, excel, macros, worksheet

I'm writing a macro in VBA for Excel. I want it to replace all worksheets except for a few. First there is a loop which deletes the unwanted sheets, and then comes another one which creates new sheets to repace them! On a first run, the macro removes unwanted sheets. However, if it is run again it seems to be unable to delete the sheets it previously created, which causes a name duplicity error.

(The rng variable is supposed to extend across the entire row but I haven't gotten to fixing that yet.)
Hope you guys can provide some insight, much appreciated!

```
sub Terminator() 
Dim Current As Worksheet
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
' Loop through all of the worksheets in the active workbook.
For Each Current In Worksheets
    If Not Current.Name = "Data" Then
        Worksheets(Current.Name).Delete
    End If
Next Current
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

' Define range for loop
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Set rng = Sheets("Data").Range("A5:M5")
' Loop through entire row, looking for employees
For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value = "Nummer" Then
        ' Make new chart for employee
        With Charts.Add
            .ChartType = xlLineMarkers
            .Name = cell.Offset(-1, 1).Value
            .HasTitle = True
            .ChartTitle.Text = cell.Offset(-1, 1).Value
            ' Set data (dynamic) and x-axis (static) for new chart
            .SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Data").Range(cell.Offset(-2, 3), cell.Offset(7, 4))
            .Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Select
            .FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Data!E4:E12"
            ' Add trendlines
            .FullSeriesCollection(1).Trendlines.Add Type:=xlLinear, Forward _
            :=0, Backward:=0, DisplayEquation:=0, DisplayRSquared:=0, Name:= _
            "Trend (DDE)"
            .FullSeriesCollection(2).Trendlines.Add Type:=xlLinear, Forward _
            :=0, Backward:=0, DisplayEquation:=0, DisplayRSquared:=0, Name:= _
            "Trend (SDE)"
        End With
        ' Chart is moved to end of all sheets
        Sheets(cell.Offset(-1, 1).Value).Move _
         after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to define the worksheet with the `Worksheets()`

```
Sub Terminator() 
Dim Current As Worksheet
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
' Loop through all of the worksheets in the active workbook.
For Each Current In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Not Current.Name = "Data" Then
        Current.Delete
    End If
Next Current
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer!  I ran the code and it works excellent the first time, but on a second run it doesn't delete the sheets created in the previous run. This raises a name duplicity error.

Comment: @MGroth what do you mean by "previous run"?  Is this running within a larger macro?

Comment: Uhm yes, further down a new sheet is created. I want to replace sheets on each run.

Comment: @MGroth can you edit your question to add this code?  Can't help if I can't see it.  My guess is that we'll need to add a `DoEvents` call somewhere to refresh the workbook data, but I need to see the code to know where/if its necessary

Comment: @MGroth looking at your code now, when you say that it can't delete them on the second pass: are you manually re-running this macro or is it being called multiple times by another macro?

Comment: @MGroth have you tried running through the `Sheets` collection instead of the `Worksheets` collection?  (Worksheets are a subset of Sheets).  Try changing `Current` to the Sheet type and running the loop through the `Sheets` collection

Comment: Omg so good to know about the subsets! I'm trying with the Shheet type, but get a 'type mismatch error' in this line "For Each Current In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets" But I'll look into it!

Comment: @MGroth you need to be sure that `Current` is defined as a `Sheet` type (not Worksheet)

Comment: I am pretty sure, it looks like this (comment removed): Dim Current As Sheets; For Each Current In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets; If Not isInArray(Sheets(Current).Name, Array("Data")) Then; ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Current).Delete; End If; Next

Comment: @MGroth Should be `Dim Current As Sheet` (note the lack of pluralization)

Comment: No, that doesn't work as Excel says "Sheet" is a user defined type which doesn't exist.

Comment: @MGroth hmm I see that now.  Well, when in doubt... `Variant` haha

Answer (score 1):

The Following code (minor changes worked in my workbook), are you sure you have the names you put in the **If** in your Workbook ?
Anyway, I think it's better to use **Select** for multiple possible mathces

```
Sub Terminator()

    Dim Current                         As Excel.Worksheet

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    ' Loop through all of the worksheets in the active workbook.
    For Each Current In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        If Not (Current.Name = "Data") Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Current.Name).Delete
        End If
    Next Current
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! If what you mean by "you have the names" is that the string "Data" is supposed to match a sheet with the name Data, then yes the names are identical. I ran the code and it works excellent the first time, but on a second run it doesn't delete the sheets created in the previous run. This raises a name duplicity error.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to the deletion is supplied by RGA, but in case you want to avoid several AND statements for each sheet that you want to retain, you can utilize a function similar to the isInArray below:

```
Sub Terminator()

Dim Current As Variant

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
' Loop through all of the worksheets in the active workbook.
For Each Current In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If Not isInArray(Current.Name, Array("Data")) Then
        Current.Delete
    End If
Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub

Function isInArray(theValue As String, vArr As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim vVal As Variant

    isInArray = False
    For Each vVal In vArr
        If LCase(vVal) = LCase(theValue) Then
            isInArray = True
        End If
    Next

End Function
```

EDIT:
function that takes a worksheet name as argument, and returns a worksheet object of that name. If the name is allready taken, the existing sheet is deleted and a new one created:

```
'example of use:
'set newWorksheet = doExist("This new Sheet")

Function doExist(strSheetName) As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim wsTest As Worksheet
    Dim nWs As Worksheet

    Set wsTest = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    'Set wsTest = wb.Worksheets(strSheetName) 'commented out in Edit of Edit
    Set wsTest = wb.Sheets(strSheetName) 'as a comment for one of the other threads reveal, the error could be the deletion of Worksheets, which would be a subgroup to Sheets of which graph sheets are no a part
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not wsTest Is Nothing Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        wsTest.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If

    'Set doExist = wb.Worksheets.Add(after:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)) 'Edit of Edit, the later call to Charts.Add does this for you
    'doExist.Name = strSheetName 'Edit of Edit, no need to return anything

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The array is such a great solution to make the code more scalable!I ran the code and it works excellent the first time, further down in the macro I create new sheets to replace the deleted ones, and on a second run these aren't removed.

Comment: I see your comment to RGA. The error must occur if you try to name a new sheet the same as an existing one, e.g. "Data". If this is the case I can give you a function I use myself for sheet creation. The function first checks if the name is already in use, and if so, deletes the existing sheet, before creation/naming of the new one

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the situation. That would be very much appreciated! Is it small enough for a comment or mail?

Comment: hmm, actually looking at your Added code, I don't think your issue resides with the creation of worksheets, but rather the chart that you are adding. Since the chart properly allready exist, you are trying to name a new chart the same as the one that is alleady there. You can tweek the doExist to do the same with a Chart

Comment: So... I will have to "flush" it in some way to be able to use the graph names again?

Comment: without your actual workbook it is hard to tell where it really goes wrong, but looking at the comments under RGA's thread, a solution is to change Current to variant, and change the for loop to loop Sheets rather than Worksheets - I've edited it in